Дублирование сообщений от apscheduler
Есть следующая рабочая конструкция:
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import apsched_mon

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    schedule = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Moscow")
    schedule.add_job(apsched_mon.day_mon1, trigger='cron', day_of_week='mon', hour=7, minute=58,
                 kwargs={'message': message})
    schedule.start()
    await message.answer('какой то текст')

файл apsched_mon
from aiogram import types

async def day_mon1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text='Текст')

Проблема заключается в том, что когда пользователь бота вводит несколько раз команду /start 2 раза, то сообщение "Текст" в функции day_mon1 будет отправляться 2 раза. Если команда будет 3 раза введена, то сообщение высылается 3 раза за 1 задачу (в 1 время) шедулера... как это исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста.
